# Textblock error with inline text

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I'm presently learning WPF and C# programing with Visual Studio 2015.

I actually get an error using TextBlock in XAML which I don't understand.

Using this code:

```
    <TextBlock>
        Text example
    </TextBlock>
```

VS shows me the following error:

A value of type 'String' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'InlineCollection'.

This error doesn't prevent compilation and the application still work but it makes programming harder as my error list box is full of messages as for every inline text there is an error message.

The only way I found to prevent the situation is to put texts with the Text="" property but this method makes formatting text way much harder.

Anybody have a solution for this issue?

Thanks.

Edit:

I should have wrote a real example of code from the book I'm reading to clarify the question:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="14"
    TextWrapping="Wrap">
        <Bold><Italic>Instructions:</Italic></Bold>
        <LineBreak />
        Select a <Underline>font</Underline> to view from the list <Italic>below</Italic>.
        <Span FontSize="10">
        You can change the text by typing in the region at the bottom.
        </Span>
</TextBlock>
```

That represent the kind of formatting I want to do.

Comment: Whenever you put a string as a `TextBlock` content it actually is converted to a `Run` inline and added to the `Inlines` collection (note that `TextBlock` is decorated with `[ContentProperty("Inlines")]` attribute. I think the error stems from the fact that the designer sometimes fails with the conversion (I don't know why though). So as cumbersome as it is, you can put all the strings in between `<Run></Run>` tags and that should make the errors go away (since `Run` has `[ContentProperty("Text")]`, which is a string, so no conversion is required.

Comment: Your TextBlock code.... works perfectly fine

Comment: @Grx70: You're right, it's cumbersome! But as it clear my error list it will make studying and practicing easier.  So I will use it for the time of my learning.

Comment: @Jim, I know the code works but not without showing errors.

Comment: @sevynos I made an empty project, tested the code you provided, and worked without any error. Must be something else ... you forgot to mention.

Comment: @Jim: You're right! I did the same and found out that if I target .Net 4.6 instead of 3.5 the errors clears out. Thanks to have made me think of testing this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the selection of .Net version as seen in the last comment to the question.

Answer (score 2):

We can use Run for inline style like

```
       <TextBlock>
      <Run Text="Hello World"></Run>
      <Underline>
          <Run Text="Hello World"></Run>
      </Underline>
        <Bold>
             <Run Text="Hello World"></Run>
        </Bold>
       </TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks for the demo code, tried it and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is this:

```
 <TextBlock Text="Text example">
```

What kind of formatting are you trying to do?  You can do things like:

```
 <TextBlock Text="Text example" FontSize="45" FontWeight="Bold">
```

There are many more options.  VS2015's Intellisense can help you discover what attributes are available.

Comment: You can look back at my question, I did an edit with some code from the book I'm using as a course.